# Is the plural for the word 'million' wrong in this context?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Passage:

> A great deal of the time you were expected to make them up out of your head. For example, the Ministry of Plenty's forecast had estimated the output of boots for the quarter at 145 million pairs. The actual output was given as **sixty-two millions**

*(George Orwell 1984)*

Additional information:

> According to this [source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/million) in this context the word 'million' should be used as singular

Question:

> Is the plural for the word 'million' wrong in this context?

[Link to the book (page #52)](http://www.planetebook.com/ebooks/1984.pdf)

Comment: Both singular and plural are idiomatic, but singular more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... both versions are grammatical, but the plural form is rare.  It considers each million to be an item, and is kind of "cute" because it invites us to think about it differently. If you want to use standard phrasing instead of being "cute", use the singular form.